# WITH Clause no longer working. "exceeded call limit on IO usage"

Tags: oracle, plsql, subquery, with-statement

I have some code that previously ran fine with no issues. But now when I run I receive the

> ORA-02395: exceeded call limit on IO usage
>   02395. 00000 -  "exceeded call limit on IO usage"

error. Can anyone explain to me why my code is throwing this error. I have no access to increase any user privileges. I've tried running this code and limiting the amount of data in the with clause and it ran fine. So I'm guessing some modifications need to happen there.

```
WITH NEW_REP_DATA AS (
    select period,manager rep,comp,sum(a) "GT99",sum(b) "90TO99",sum(c) "80TO89",sum(d) "70TO79",sum(e) "LT70",sum(f) "NA" from (
    select period
    ,rep_code
    ,manager
    --,nvl(a,0)+nvl(b,0)+nvl(c,0)+nvl(d,0)+nvl(e,0)+nvl(f,0) cnt
    ,comp,
    nvl(a,0) a,nvl(b,0) b, nvl(c,0) c, nvl(d,0) d,nvl(e,0) e,nvl(f,0) f
    from
    (select period,rep_code,manager, comp,max(case when bucket='>99' then cnt end) a,
    max(case when bucket='90TO99' then cnt end) b,
    max(case when bucket='80TO89' then cnt end) c,
    max(case when bucket= '70TO79' then cnt end) d,
    max(case when bucket='LT70' then cnt end) e,
    max(case when bucket='NA' then cnt end) f
    from (
    select period,rep_code,manager, comp,bucket,
    --count(unique rep_code)
    count( distinct rep_code) cnt
    --cnt
    from(
    select * from (select
    unique period
    ,MANAGER
    ,"PayeeID" rep_code
    ,comp
    ,cytd cytd_a
    ,cytp cytd_p,
    nvl(case when cytp > 0 then
      case when round((cytd/cytp),3) > .99 then '>99'
           when round((cytd/cytp),3) between .891 and .99 then '90TO99'
           when round((cytd/cytp),3) between .791 and .89 then '80TO89'
           when round((cytd/cytp),3) between .7 and .79 then '70TO79'
           when round((cytd/cytp),3) < .7 then 'LT70'
      end
    when  cytp = 0 and cytd > 0 then '>99'
    else 'NA'
    end,'NA') as bucket
    from (
    select aaa.period
    ,aaa."PayeeID"
    ,aaa."Reports_to" MANAGER
    ,aaa."Component" comp,
    aaa."Current_YTD_Actual" cytd,
    aaa."Current_YTD_Plan" cytp
    from nbr_var_data aaa
    where aaa."Comp_Plan_Name" not in ('MISC_COMP','GM_2017')
    AND "Comp_Plan_Name" not in ('MISC_COMP')
    AND "Comp_Plan_Name" not LIKE '%GM%'
    and aaa.period = (select max(aaa.period) from  Nbr_Var_Data)
    ))
    )
    where 1=1
    group by period, rep_code, comp, bucket, manager )
    group by period, rep_code, comp, manager )) group by period, manager, comp)

    SELECT DISTINCT
    dc.rep PID
    ,dc.period
    ,ee.PAYEE_NAM
    ,dc.comp
    ,Dc."GT99"
    ,Dc."90TO99"
    ,Dc."80TO89"
    ,Dc."70TO79"
    ,Dc."LT70"
    ,Dc."NA"
    ,Ee.Parent_Payee_Id REPORT_TO_PAYEE_ID
    ,Ee.Parent_Payee_Nam REPORT_TO_NAME
    FROM (SELECT
    --period ,
    --empl_id ,
    gg.payee_id ,
    gg.payee_nam ,
    --lvl ,
    ff.parent_payee_id ,
    ff.PARENT_PAYEE_NAM
    --parent_lvl ,
    --mnth_disp
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
    dd.period
    ,dd.PARENT_PAYEE_ID
    ,ee.PAYEE_NAM PARENT_PAYEE_NAM
    from (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      PERIOD,
      PARENT_PAYEE_ID
    FROM FI_CHANNEL_HIER) dd
    left join FI_CHANNEL_HIER ee
    on dd.PARENT_PAYEE_ID = ee.PAYEE_ID
    WHERE DD.PERIOD = (select max(DD.PERIOD) from  FI_CHANNEL_HIER )) ff
    LEFT JOIN FI_CHANNEL_HIER gg
    ON ff.PARENT_PAYEE_ID = gg.PARENT_PAYEE_ID) ee,
    NEW_REP_DATA dc
    WHERE EE.PAYEE_ID = DC.Rep
    ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ORA-02395 happens when your query exceeds the LOGICAL_READS_PER_CALL threshold set in your user profile. That's why the issue goes away when you restricted the amount of data returned by your subquery.

Two possible explanations for why this did not use to happen:

1. The tables contain more data than they used to be.
2. Your DBA has implemented a new user profile (or made the existing one stricter).

The obvious solution is to negotiate with the DBA.

Otherwise you will need to refactor your query to reduce the number of blocks it scans. Doing requires an understanding of your data model, your business logic and your data characteristics (volume, distribution, usage).

Clearly that requires knowledge of and access to your system, so it's not something that we can help with.

Answer (score -2):

```
WITH NEW_REP_DATA AS (
select period,manager rep,comp,sum(a) "GT99",sum(b) "90TO99",sum(c) "80TO89",sum(d) "70TO79",sum(e) "LT70",sum(f) "NA" from (
select period
,rep_code
,manager
--,nvl(a,0)+nvl(b,0)+nvl(c,0)+nvl(d,0)+nvl(e,0)+nvl(f,0) cnt
,comp,
nvl(a,0) a,nvl(b,0) b, nvl(c,0) c, nvl(d,0) d,nvl(e,0) e,nvl(f,0) f
from
(select period,rep_code,manager, comp,max(case when bucket='>99' then cnt end) a,
max(case when bucket='90TO99' then cnt end) b,
max(case when bucket='80TO89' then cnt end) c,
max(case when bucket= '70TO79' then cnt end) d,
max(case when bucket='LT70' then cnt end) e,
max(case when bucket='NA' then cnt end) f
from (
select period,rep_code,manager, comp,bucket,
--count(unique rep_code)
count( distinct rep_code) cnt
--cnt
from(
select * from (select
unique period
,MANAGER
,"PayeeID" rep_code
,comp
,cytd cytd_a
,cytp cytd_p,
nvl(case when cytp > 0 then
  case when round((cytd/cytp),3) > .99 then '>99'
       when round((cytd/cytp),3) between .891 and .99 then '90TO99'
       when round((cytd/cytp),3) between .791 and .89 then '80TO89'
       when round((cytd/cytp),3) between .7 and .79 then '70TO79'
       when round((cytd/cytp),3) < .7 then 'LT70'
  end
when  cytp = 0 and cytd > 0 then '>99'
else 'NA'
end,'NA') as bucket
from (
select aaa.period
,aaa."PayeeID"
,aaa."Reports_to" MANAGER
,aaa."Component" comp,
aaa."Current_YTD_Actual" cytd,
aaa."Current_YTD_Plan" cytp
from nbr_var_data aaa
where aaa."Comp_Plan_Name" not in ('MISC_COMP','GM_2017')
AND "Comp_Plan_Name" not in ('MISC_COMP')
AND "Comp_Plan_Name" not LIKE '%GM%'
and aaa.period = (select max(aaa.period) from  Nbr_Var_Data)
))
)
where 1=1
group by period, rep_code, comp, bucket, manager )
group by period, rep_code, comp, manager )) group by period, manager, comp)
SELECT DISTINCT
dc.rep PID
,dc.period
,ee.PAYEE_NAM
,dc.comp
,Dc."GT99"
,Dc."90TO99"
,Dc."80TO89"
,Dc."70TO79"
,Dc."LT70"
,Dc."NA"
,Ee.Parent_Payee_Id REPORT_TO_PAYEE_ID
,Ee.Parent_Payee_Nam REPORT_TO_NAME
FROM (SELECT
--period ,
--empl_id ,
gg.payee_id ,
gg.payee_nam ,
--lvl ,
ff.parent_payee_id ,
ff.PARENT_PAYEE_NAM
--parent_lvl ,
--mnth_disp
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
dd.period
,dd.PARENT_PAYEE_ID
,ee.PAYEE_NAM PARENT_PAYEE_NAM
from (
SELECT DISTINCT
  PERIOD,
  PARENT_PAYEE_ID
FROM FI_CHANNEL_HIER) dd
left join FI_CHANNEL_HIER ee
on dd.PARENT_PAYEE_ID = ee.PAYEE_ID
WHERE DD.PERIOD = (select max(DD.PERIOD) from  FI_CHANNEL_HIER )) ff
LEFT JOIN FI_CHANNEL_HIER gg
ON ff.PARENT_PAYEE_ID = gg.PARENT_PAYEE_ID) ee,
NEW_REP_DATA dc
WHERE EE.PAYEE_ID = DC.Rep
AND dc.period = (select max(period) from  NEW_REP_DATA)
;
```